# Embed react-native-web app into existing website

Tags: react-native, webpack, elementor, react-native-web

I want to embed a [react-native-web](https://github.com/necolas/react-native-web) application into an existing website and am currently looking for options how to do so.

The application should be a quite simple questionnaire which needs to be embedded into a website created with Elementor. My idea was to use the [Elementor HTML widget](https://docs.elementor.com/article/294-html) and insert my application somehow, but unfortunately I cannot figure out how to do this.

I've got a bit of experience developing React Native(RN) apps but I am pretty new to web development and therefore thought it would be easier for me to go with RN and the react-native-web library.

So far, I've created a RN project using `npx react-native init WebApp`, copied the *App.js*, *index.js* and *package.json* files from react-native-web [CodeSandbox template](https://codesandbox.io/s/q4qymyp2l6), deleted the *node_modules* folders and ran `npm install`. Then I was able to start and build this example web app with the scripts from the *package.json*.

Now my question, how can I use the output from the **build** directory and embed it into an html tag?

I also tried to use [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) with the configuration from the [react-native-web docs](http://necolas.github.io/react-native-web/docs/?path=/docs/guides-multi-platform--page#web-packaging-for-existing-react-native-apps) to bundle the app but I always got a new error as soon as I fixed the last one. Is it possible to bundle a RN app into a single JS file which I could then insert into the website?

Looking forward to any advice!

Marco

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using the below webpack config. The created bundle.web.js' content is put into a script tag (`<script>...</script>`). This can be embedded into the HTML widget.

```
// web/webpack.config.js

const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

const appDirectory = path.resolve(__dirname, '');

// This is needed for webpack to compile JavaScript.
// Many OSS React Native packages are not compiled to ES5 before being
// published. If you depend on uncompiled packages they may cause webpack build
// errors. To fix this webpack can be configured to compile to the necessary
// `node_module`.
const babelLoaderConfiguration = {
  test: /\.js$/,
  // Add every directory that needs to be compiled by Babel during the build.
  include: [
    path.resolve(appDirectory, 'index.web.js'),
    path.resolve(appDirectory, 'src'),
    path.resolve(appDirectory, 'node_modules/react-native-uncompiled'),
  ],
  use: {
    loader: 'babel-loader',
    options: {
      cacheDirectory: true,
      // The 'metro-react-native-babel-preset' preset is recommended to match React Native's packager
      presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
      // Re-write paths to import only the modules needed by the app
      plugins: ['react-native-web'],
    },
  },
};

// This is needed for webpack to import static images in JavaScript files.
const imageLoaderConfiguration = {
  test: /\.(gif|jpe?g|png|svg)$/,
  use: {
    loader: 'url-loader',
    options: {
      name: '[name].[ext]',
    },
  },
};

module.exports = {
  entry: [
    // load any web API polyfills
    // path.resolve(appDirectory, 'polyfills-web.js'),
    // your web-specific entry file
    path.resolve(appDirectory, 'src/index.js'),
  ],

  // configures where the build ends up
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.web.js',
    path: path.resolve(appDirectory, 'dist'),
  },

  // ...the rest of your config

  module: {
    rules: [babelLoaderConfiguration, imageLoaderConfiguration],
  },

  resolve: {
    // This will only alias the exact import "react-native"
    alias: {
      'react-native$': 'react-native-web',
    },
    // If you're working on a multi-platform React Native app, web-specific
    // module implementations should be written in files using the extension
    // `.web.js`.
    extensions: ['.web.js', '.js'],
  },
};
```